# jQuery Include All in Drop Down Filter

Tags: jquery

I am working to create a table with drop down filters. I have it working right now but I have a problem in that I have been unable to figure out how to include results set with "All". (Ignore the Search Filter and Focus only on Drop Downs).

Do you have an idea to always show the column rows with "All" value?

Please see example:

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.filter').change(function () {
    var values = [];

     $('.filter').each(function () {
        var colIdx = $(this).data('col');

         $(this).find('option:selected').each(function () {
             if ($(this).val() != "") values.push( {
                text: $(this).text(),
                colId : colIdx
             });
        });
    });
    filter('table > tbody > tr', values);
});

function filter(selector, values) {
    $(selector).each(function () {
        var sel = $(this);
        var tokens = sel.text().trim().split('\n');
        var toknesObj1 = [], i;
        for(i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
            toknesObj1[i] = {
               text:tokens[i].trim(), 
               found:false
            };
        }

        var show = false;
        $.each(values, function (i, val) {                

       if (toknesObj1[val.colId].text.search(new RegExp("\\b"+val.text+"\\b")) >= 0) {
           toknesObj1[val.colId].found = true;
          }

        });          
        var count = 0;
         $.each(toknesObj1, function (i, val) {
             if (val.found){
                 count+=1;
             }
         });
        show = (count === values.length);        
        show ? sel.show() : sel.hide();
    });
}
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#uniSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#university-1 tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uni-dropdown">
  <select id="year" class="filter" data-col="0">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="2019">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
  </select>
  <select id="model" class="filter" data-col="1">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Model</option>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="Model I">Model I</option>
    <option value="Model II">Model II</option>
  </select>
  <select id="type" class="filter" data-col="4">
    <option value ="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
    <option value="Component">Component</option>
    <option value="Video">Video</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="uniSearch" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<table id = "university-1">
  <thead>
 <tr>
      <th data-title="Information"><h3>Year</h3></th>
      <th><h3>Model</h3></th>
      <th><h3>Title</h3></th>
      <th><h3>Manual</h3></th>
      <th><h3>Type</h3></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2020</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2020</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2020</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Component</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">All</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Component</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2020</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">All</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Component</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2016</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
    
        <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">All</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Component</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2016</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2016</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">All</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Manual</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Component</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2015</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2020</td>
      <td data-title="Model">All</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">All</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model II</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">2019</td>
      <td data-title="Model">All</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Year">All</td>
      <td data-title="Model">Model I</td>
      <td data-title="Title">Owner's Manual</td>
      <td data-title="Manual"><a class="wplightbox" href="#" target="_blank">View</a> | <a href="#" download="#">Download</a></td>
      <td data-title="Type">Video</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, I tried using the search and it always shows All in the results. What specific place do you want to show All in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question and your code correctly, it looks like you can solve this by changing your regex which searches for the dropdown value to include an alternation for the value `All`:

```
if (toknesObj1[val.colId].text.search(new RegExp("\\b("+val.text+"|All)\\b")) >= 0) {
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. All my searches kept taking me to ARRAYS .... Thank you Nick!